# Apache Timer is running twice

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel

Apache timer is triggering twice in Spring DSL xml. its triggering time gap of 2 or 3 seconds. every time when the timer triggers it will trigger twice and my code executed twice.
Please help me out any parameter i can set or any other solution to stop the duplicate trigger.

```
<from id= "Timer" uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=3000"/>
```

Comment: As per my requirement route that generates an event every 30 seconds only once :Timer <from id= "Timer" uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=3000"/>

Comment: `period=3000` means 3000ms, or 3 seconds.  NOT 30 seconds.

Comment: even i configured with 30s and 60s still its calling twice in the interval gap of 4 seconds

Comment: Pollar Trigger :04:01:55.582
Pollar Trigger :04:01:59.010

Pollar Trigger :04:02:55.582
Pollar Trigger :04:01:59.010

Comment: You may have 2 routes or something, or what you log is printed twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. Without setting "synchronous" a timer task will be gernerated for every period regardless if the previous instance has completed. If you only want one timer tasks running at eny point in time, set synchronous to true - see https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/timer-component.adoc

synchronous (advanced - default: false)

Sets whether synchronous processing should be strictly used, or Camel is allowed to use asynchronous processing (if supported).